# A/B Test: Determine if a Lift in Measured Sales is Significant

Tags: ab-test

I am no stats expert so any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I’m working on a post-campaign analysis to determine if any measured sales lift (sales lift per audience) is significant between test and control treatment groups.   From what I have been reading, I believe you could potentially use an Anova or Ancova to run a post-campaign analysis to determine if any measured sales lift is above or below a standard deviation or margin of error?

My question is, does this make sense?  I’m never run an ANOVA is SAS is there any sample code one can share?

Comment: You should probably ask this on on stats.stackexchange.com - its a statistics question and that's where the statistics experts are.

Comment: @Spacedman I don't think why this is not on-topic here. It is on-topic on CV alright, but there's no reason to migrate it there when it is on-topic and can be answered here :)

Comment: Can it be answered here? Given that cross-posting is frowned on and there's an order of magnitude more activity on CV, it is much more likely to get a good answer there. The question to ask is not "is it on-topic on DS?" but "is it off-topic on CV?". It's not off-topic on CV, so that's a better place for it. DS is not the right place for non stats experts to try and get statistical advice.

Comment: There's a similar question here the [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/199881/37263) to which might be useful to you.

Comment: I went head a reposed on CV.